# Prevent overriding of file accept for git operations

Tags: git, file, unix

I collaborate coding with someone who is not so tech-savy and prefers to edit files directly on the server, which usually leads to a mess. I advised him to use a version controll sytem (git) instead, but he seems to be reluctant.  Is there a way to prevent the respective files to be overriden by him, except for changes that come through git?

Unfortunately, I don't have full control over the system and there is only one user available, so what I cannot do is to change the rights according to the user and access git via the more powerful user.

Comment: That's more an organizational/educational problem so I'm skeptical if turning it into a technical issue would help. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122150/how-can-i-convince-cowboy-programmers-to-use-source-control

Comment: It would definitely help, because it would forcefully remind that guy to use git.

Comment: Git doesn't offer protection against changing files directly.

Comment: My point is that you're solving the wrong problem. Applying more force will trigger a stronger counter reaction. More context: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/118973/how-do-i-motivate-usage-of-git-for-the-next-maintainer

Answer (score 0):

You could create a cron-job that reverts any changes on the server every 5 minutes or so. That way manually editing files on the server will have an effect, but only a shortlived one.

But I agree with people in the comments that this looks more like an organizational problem.